# UWP equivalent of cipher.doFinal() of a SHA1 MessageDigest

Tags: java, c#, android, uwp

The following is the android code:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");//No I18N
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            PrivateKeyEntry pKey = (PrivateKeyEntry) Application.getInstance(appcontext)
                    .getKeyStore()
                    .getEntry(KEY_STORE_ALIAS, null);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pKey.getPrivateKey());

            byte[] encBytes = cipher.doFinal(messageDigest);

String encryptedData = new String(Base64.encode(encBytes, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");

return encryptedData;
```

The following is the uwp code:

```
IBuffer dataBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText).AsBuffer();
            IBuffer KeyPairBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(keyPairString).AsBuffer();


            AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider asymmetricKeyAlgorithm = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaSignPkcs1Sha1);
            CryptographicKey cryptographicKey = asymmetricKeyAlgorithm.ImportKeyPair(KeyPairBuffer);

            HashAlgorithmProvider hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1);
            IBuffer hashedBuffer = hashAlgorithm.HashData(dataBuffer);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBuffer.ToArray()));

            var buffer = CryptographicEngine.SignHashedData(cryptographicKey, hashedBuffer);

            return Convert.ToBase64String((buffer.ToArray()));'
```

The android code works properly, but the UWP code doesn't.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What  "UWP code doesn't work"  mean here? Did the code throw any exceptions? Or the return result is not as expect?

Comment: I have tried using all the methods of the CryptographicEngine class
Like
CryptographicEngine.SignAsync(),
CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(),
CryptographicEngine.SignHashedData(),

and for different methods I got different Exceptions,
Like
Error: Signature Verification Failed,
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error,
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes

Answer (score 0):

> I got different Exceptions, Like Error: Signature Verification Failed, javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error, javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes –

I tested the code snippet in UWP and cannot reproduce your issue. Since your code snippet are incomplete, here is the completed code snippet that can run successfully on my side.

```
string plainText = "test";
IBuffer dataBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText).AsBuffer();
//IBuffer KeyPairBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(keyPairString).AsBuffer();  
AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider asymmetricKeyAlgorithm = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaSignPkcs1Sha1);
CryptographicKey cryptographicKey = asymmetricKeyAlgorithm.CreateKeyPair(512);
//CryptographicKey cryptographicKey = asymmetricKeyAlgorithm.ImportKeyPair(buffKeyPair);
HashAlgorithmProvider hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1);
IBuffer hashedBuffer = hashAlgorithm.HashData(dataBuffer);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBuffer.ToArray()));
var buffer = CryptographicEngine.SignHashedData(cryptographicKey, hashedBuffer);
```

Especially, the exceptions you mentioned here are looks like the Java exception, not c#. So that please firstly ensure which code line thrown the exception. And then check if the `keyPairString` is correctly. Pay attention that typical key sizes are 512, 1024, 2048, or 4096 bits.

For more details please reference the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/cryptography).

Comment: I have the idea about the key sizes, but I need to encrypt, decrypt and also sign data based on the requirement, with the same keys. And yeah the exception I have sent are java exceptions, the exceptions that I received from the server side.
I am creating the keys once with the algorithm names as
`AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1`
and am supposed to use the same keys for encrypting, decrypting and signing data.
@SunteenWu

Comment: The same thing in android I use X509certificates is there any equivalent I am supposed to use. Like
`cryptographicKey.ExportPublicKey(CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.X509SubjectPublicKeyInfo)
cryptographicKey.Export(CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.xxx)`

But there is no X509 for the private key.

Comment: @TrikutamGargeyaSaiNikhil what issue you currently is trying to resolve?   Any relationships between the server side exceptions with your uwp app code snippet?

Comment: The issue is for the same server code, my android code works whereas my UWP code doesn't and I have no clue why?

Comment: Can I contact you somehow @SunteenWu
or Any time you might be present in the chat.

Comment: I was checking the server side(java) part, they decrypt the data with the public key, and hash the unencrypted data, to compare these both.
The decrypted Hash has a some additional data of about 10 charecters infront if the actual supposed to be data.